# Writing proxy pass in haproxy

Tags: apache, nginx, configuration, proxy, haproxy

How can I write this proxy pass example 
from nginx:

```
location /appDir/ {
        proxy_pass https://Name/appDir/;
    }
```

to haproxy

additionally:
the below is from haproxy site.

```
 # ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://bk.dom.com/bar
 http-request set-header Host bk.dom.com
 reqirep  ^([^ :]*)\ /mirror/foo/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

But where does /bar go from the commented-out part?